# Angular httpclient.post does not create the right body

Tags: angular, post, httpclient

I have an angular service that has to send some data with a post call.

The class that I have to send is:

```
   export class Informazioni {
   partitaivacf:string;
   idpaese:string;
   }
```

The template:

```
          <label for="idpaese">ID</label>
          <input #idpaese type="text" placeholder="ID Paese" [(ngModel)]="informazioni.idpaese">

          <label for="partitaivacf">Partita iva o codice fiscale</label>
          <input #partitaivacf type="text" placeholder="PIVA" [(ngModel)]="informazioni.partitaivacf">
```

The component:

```
      export class ImpostazioniFattureComponent implements OnInit {

      informazioni:Informazioni;



      constructor(private informazioniservice:InformazioniService) {
      this.informazioniservice.prendiinformazioni().subscribe(result => {
      if(result != undefined) {
      this.informazioni = result;
      }
      });
      }

      ngOnInit() {}


       salva(){
      this.informazioniservice.salvainformazioni(this.informazioni);
      }
```

And the service:

```
     export class InformazioniService {

     endpoint = 'http://localhost:8080/';

     constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

     salvainformazioni(info:Informazioni){

     var post = this.http.post(this.endpoint + 'salvainformazioni', info);
     console.log(post);
     post.subscribe( result => {
     });
     }

     prendiinformazioni(): Observable<Informazioni>{
     return this.http.get<Informazioni>(this.endpoint + 'prendiinformazioni');
     }
```

}

For the other objects the body of the request is like

```
  ClassName 
  {
   "attr1":"val1",
   ...
   "attrN":"valN"
  }
```

In this case, if I print the post object on the console, it is only

```
  {  
   "idpaese":"id",
   "partitaivacf":"piva"
  }
```

Obviously, when I open the page of the template, is thrown an error that the template cannot read the properties of the undefined informazioni object. Could be the problem of generated body related to it? Or could be another problem that I am ignoring?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem does not have anything to do with the httpClient.

It seems from your explanation that you are expecting the body of the post to include the "ClassName" object, but what you are actually posting is an "Informazioni" object, and that object's only members, as your definition shows, are "idpaese" and "partitaivacf".

I'm guessing that you're just a bit confused about the data that you actually defined vs. the data that you expect.

A stackblitz example showing your code, along with a detailed description of how you expect it to work vs. how it is actually working, would help folks to direct you to a more concrete solution.